# Change MySQL /tmp to /somedrive/mysqltmp in centos 7 for error code 28

Tags: mysql, centos7, tmp

I am trying to change the temp location for MySQL from default `/tmp` to `/somedrive/mysqltmp` as i am getting

> Errcode: 28 - No space left on device

```
Solution: 1
```

I tried to add a line in `/etc/my.cnf` as `tmpdir=/somedrive/mysqltmp`

then issued  `sudo service mysql stop` and  `sudo service mysql start`

After restart, i still see `ERROR` remains.

```
Solution: 2
```

Based on [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/temporary-files.html) I tried

```
mysqld --verbose --help | grep tmp

tmp-table-size     16777216
tmpdir             /tmp
```

and then i tried

`mysqld --tmpdir=/somedrive/mysqltmp`

to change the defaults. But i am not able to change the tmp directory. I am not sure what i am missing!

> 

### I figured this out: Do changes under

`[mysqld]` as

```
tmpdir=/somedrive/mysqltmp
```

and then issue  `sudo service mysql stop` and  `sudo service mysql start`

Now check:

```
mysqld --verbose --help | grep tmp

tmp-table-size     16777216
tmpdir             /somedrive/mysqltmp
```

Comment: Usually, `/tmp` is a temporary device stored in memory that has a lot of free space. Maybe you want to enlarge that device?

Comment: @NicoHaase Not many want to do that on a production system. Moreover, there are posts that support how to do it but in my case, i had an additional label specifier. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do changes under

`[mysqld]` as

```
tmpdir=/somedrive/mysqltmp
```

and then issue  `sudo service mysql stop` and  `sudo service mysql start`

Now check:

```
mysqld --verbose --help | grep tmp

tmp-table-size     16777216
tmpdir             /somedrive/mysqltmp
```

Answer (score 1):

This has happened to me before because mysql was using a my.cnf in a different location.  Search for another my.cnf.  You could also try moving the my.cnf file that you know of and see if mysql complains.

Comment: `sudo find / -name '*.cnf'`

`/etc/my.cnf`
`/var/lib/mysql/auto.cnf`
`/usr/share/doc/mysql-community-server-5.6.35/my-default.cnf`
`/usr/share/mysql/my-default.cnf`